# How to reshape numpy array of shape (26400, 1, 0, 1, 2048) to shape (26400, None, None, 2048)

Tags: python, numpy

Looking for a solution to reshape numpy array from shape (26400, 1, 0, 1, 2048) to (264400, None, None, 2048)

Comment: Is 264400 a typo, and should be 26400?

Comment: Also if there's a `0` in the array, that means that the array is empty, so what would a reshape help with?

Comment: yes @Sohan J as you have it defined right now, your array does not make sense.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a numpy issue. Could it be related to tensorflow?

Comment: @user2653663 sorry for the typo in the question. Yes this is a tensorflow related issue

Comment: Is there a way to access elements in this array and create a new array of shape (26400, None, None, 2048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st in Google on "numpy remove dimensions 1" is [numpy.squeeze — NumPy v1.16 Manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
In [3]: z=np.zeros((100,1,0,1,100))

In [5]: z.squeeze()
Out[5]: array([], shape=(100L, 0L, 100L), dtype=float64)
```

As others have suggested, there's no such dimension size as `None` in `numpy`. If you try to create `numpy.array` with such a "dimension size", you will (as of NumPy 1.16) get `None`, and a `DeprecationWarning` will be printed noting that this semantic will soon be removed.

And removing a dimension of `0` is not possible because it means that your array is empty, and if it's removed, the result won't be empty any more, so you will need something to fill it with.

In [comment98113945](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716103/how-to-reshape-numpy-array-of-shape-26400-1-0-1-2048-to-shape-26400-none/55716530?noredirect=1#comment98113945_55716530) , you mentioned that your "`None`" size is a requirement of some function. In this context, I believe, "`None`" means "any size".

Comment: I tried squeeze and compress, but didn't work...Is there a way to access elements in this array and create a new array of shape (26400, None, None, 2048)...PS: This is tensorflow related issue

Comment: @SohanJ As I explained in the edit, there's no such thing as a dimension of the size "None", and you cannot access the elements of your array because it has no elements, it's empty.

Comment: @SohanJ  If you explain what you are trying to do, we may better understand what kind of array you really need...

Comment: So I'm trying to perform transfer learning through InceptionV3 network. First I removed the dense connections at the top and recorded the output through the ConvNet. Next I am trying to train the dense connected layers at the top with these recorded output. Now I need to make sure the earlier recorded output matches the input of the top layers. Problem is that the recorded output is of shape 26400, 1, 0, 1, 2048 (where each data point is of shape 1,0,1,2048) and the dense top layer expects input of shape None, None, None, 2048

Comment: @SohanJ Whatever the problem with your code is, such dimensions means that your recorded output has NO data, for whatever reason. Please ask a separate question about this and make sure to include a [mcve] into it for us to be able to help.

Comment: @SohanJ I hypothesize that "None" in the context of size requirements means "any size".

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SohanJ If the answer resolved the issue, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.